# Broken Atlantis webpage running on EKS deployment with ingress-alb

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-eks, atlantis

I have deployed atlantis based on original documents on EKS,
[text](https://www.runatlantis.io/docs/deployment.html)
I have added ingress to use AWS-loadbalancer-controller to create ALb with ACM certificate for encryption and using externalDNS to create DNS record on Route53.
Now Atlantis is running and the loadbalancer created and the Record on Route53 is created as well, the Atlantis webpage is broken and not loading correctly ( below snapshot)

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: atlantis
  namespace: atlantis
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: atlantis
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app.kubernetes.io/name: atlantis
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app.kubernetes.io/name: atlantis
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: atlantis
        image: ghcr.io/runatlantis/atlantis:v0.27.1 # 1. Replace <VERSION> with the most recent release.
        env:
        - name: ATLANTIS_REPO_ALLOWLIST
          value: github.com/**********/test/* # 2. Replace this with your own repo allowlist.

        ### GitHub Config ###
        - name: ATLANTIS_GH_USER
          value: test-user # 3i. If you're using GitHub replace <YOUR_GITHUB_USER> with the username of your Atlantis GitHub user without the `@`.
        - name: ATLANTIS_GH_TOKEN
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              name: atlantis-vcs
              key: token
        - name: ATLANTIS_GH_WEBHOOK_SECRET
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              name: atlantis-vcs
              key: webhook-secret
        ### End GitHub Config ###

        - name: ATLANTIS_PORT
          value: "4141" # Kubernetes sets an ATLANTIS_PORT variable so we need to override.
        ports:
        - name: atlantis
          containerPort: 4141
        resources:
          requests:
            memory: 512Mi
            cpu: 100m
          limits:
            memory: 512Mi
            cpu: 100m
        livenessProbe:
          # We only need to check every 60s since Atlantis is not a
          # high-throughput service.
          periodSeconds: 60
          httpGet:
            path: /healthz
            port: 4141
            # If using https, change this to HTTPS
            scheme: HTTP
        readinessProbe:
          periodSeconds: 60
          httpGet:
            path: /healthz
            port: 4141
            # If using https, change this to HTTPS
            scheme: HTTP
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: atlantis
  namespace: atlantis
spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  ports:
  - name: atlantis
    port: 80
    targetPort: 4141
  selector:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: atlantis
---
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: atlantis
  namespace: atlantis
  annotations:
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/scheme: internet-facing
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/group.name: atlantis
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/target-type: ip
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/certificate-arn: arn:aws:acm:****************
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/listen-ports: '[{"HTTPS":443}]'
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: '443'
spec:
  ingressClassName: alb
  rules:
    - host: atlantis.example.com
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            pathType: Exact
            backend:
              service:
                name: atlantis
                port:
                  number: 80
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rX3Ii.png)

The same deployment without ingress, exposing the service as LoadBalancer can load the page correctly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `pathType` in the `Ingress` should `Prefix`. Since the path is `Exact`, only the HTML which is actually served at the root path is being served, and other queries are rejected. `Prefix` type will allow all requests as long as those match the root path

```
  pathType: Prefix
```

See the following description from the docs:

> **Path types**
>
> Each path in an Ingress is required to have a corresponding path type. Paths
> that do not include an explicit pathType will fail validation. There
> are three supported path types:
>
> - **ImplementationSpecific**: With this path type, matching is up to the
>   IngressClass. Implementations can treat this as a separate pathType or
>   treat it identically to Prefix or Exact path types.
> - **Exact**: Matches the URL path exactly and with case sensitivity.
> - **Prefix**: Matches based on a URL path prefix split by /. Matching is
>   case sensitive and done on a path element by element basis. A path
>   element refers to the list of labels in the path split by the /
>   separator. A request is a match for path p if every p is an
>   element-wise prefix of p of the request path.

Ref: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/#path-types